# Center Spin turntable

Tags: video-editor

I am doing now a Turntable video Project similar to https://www.jamesallen.com/engagement-rings/solitaire/14k-white-gold-15mm-comfort-fit-engagement-ring-item-22606

I am right now working a lot time to make sure that the item is exactly entered on the turntable so it should look good

Is there any software that could fix the video if it was not centered while capturing?

see here https://arqspin.com/product-tour/manage/dewobbler/ this website does a good job but it converts it to images, and even if you export it as a video it will become bumpy like a gif...

Or does anyone have any experience or ideas how i could make sure that it is exactly centered?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would think you could make sure it's centered by having a horizontal object (just a dowel, or something) placed at the center of the item. Turn on the turntable, then look at it through your camera's viewfinder. If the dowel moves back and forth horizontally, then it's not centered on the dowel.

As for fixing in post, it's certainly possible, though maybe a little time consuming. BTW, the "fixed" video in the dewobbler example still has a small amount of wobble that I personally find more irritating than the original large wobble. But maybe it's just me.

To fix it in post, you need to mentally define the center of your object. Then as it moves back and forth, move the center of the object to the center of the frame and set a keyframe. The keyframes will probably create a periodic pattern like a sine wave or something similar. In fact, it seems like that's mainly what they were doing in the dewobbler video - just setting keyframes for moving the center. This can be done in most video editors or motion graphics apps like FCPX, Motion, Premiere, After Effects, etc. Just use the normal transform tool.